# Need help to understand how this find command works

Tags: macos, command-line

I'm a beginner on OS X and I believe this command will make a list of all files and subfolders of specific folders

```
find /Volumes/Documents/ -exec stat -f "%N %Sm" {} + >~/Desktop/test.txt
```

I don't know how to figure out what this actually does.

Comment: find and stat are in man - what is the issue

Comment: I'm pretty much beginner for the command line of OSX. So, I would like to know why It's composed like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you posted has two parts

- `find /Volumes/Documents/ -exec stat -f "%N %Sm" {} +`
- `>~/Desktop/test.txt`

The second part is easier to explain, it just writes all the output of the first one into a file called `test.txt` which is stored on your desktop. If you leave that part out, the result of `find` will be directly written into your Terminal window.

The first part is the actual `find` command. A call to `find` basically gets two kinds of parameters

- one or several paths acting as starting point for the search (`/Volumes/Documents/` in your case)
- one or several expressions aka "find commands" which get applied to every file/folder found

A simple version would look like `find /Volumes/Documents/ -print` which just prints every file/folder found.

In your example the expression part is a bit more elaborated:

- `-exec` runs a command on the results of find (`stat -f "%N %Sm"` actually)
- `stat` gives info about a file.
- The `-f` option for stat displays information using a specified format.
- `%N %Sm` is the format used by `-f`.

  - `%` means a format string.
  - `N` means to print the file name.
  - `Sm` means to print the date modified for the file.
- `{} +` is replaced by as many found files/as possible in each call to `stat`

For more information on understanding commands, see the man page for `find` and `stat`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail information. I would appreciated it. Sorry I have no enough reputation to up vote yet.